# uploading multipart file to another server

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload

I'm working on a spring boot / Angular 6 application, I want to upload files to a server, I followed this tutorial to upload a multipart file :" https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/angular-5-upload-get-multipartfile-to-from-spring-boot-server ". The upload of the file is on a folder in the application but now I want to upload the files to another server with URL; f.e : localhost:8081/uploads : it's another server, how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is both unclear and too broad. If you want Angular to send the file to a different url, then change the URL - what's the problem? If you want your Java to upload the file to somewhere, then do some basic research in how you can upload files from Java (the specifics will depend on the protocol you are using, which needs to be supported by the server you are uploading the file to).

Comment: I am also looking for solution to this problem. Kindly post solution if you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with spring rest template and construct the body as below

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("files", getTestFile());
body.add("files", getTestFile());
body.add("files", getTestFile());

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
  = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8081/upload/";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
  .postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```